# GET request with httr does not return expected content in response

Tags: r, api, curl, httr

Survey Solutions is a survey website that has it's API documentation [here](https://demo.mysurvey.solutions/apidocs/index.html). In that list, I'm trying to make `Single assigment details` to work. But I can't make it!

```
library(httr)

GET("demo.mysurvey.solutions/api/v1/assignments/2858",
    authenticate(user = "Headquarters1", password = "Headquarters1"))
```

I get a successful 200 status code, but with `content length = 0`.

I should be able to see information about assignment 2858, viewable here: https://demo.mysurvey.solutions/Assignments/2858 (you may need to access through https://demo.mysurvey.solutions/, username and password are both `Headquarters1`). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://

```
GET("https://demo.mysurvey.solutions/Assignments/2858",
    authenticate(user = "Headquarters1", password = "Headquarters1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late answer but headquarters role user doesn't have permissions to access api endpoints, you need to use credentials for the dedicated api user.